# Can't see camera composition guides using default dark theme in 2.83

Tags: camera

I tried looking for the theme setting to change the color of the camera composition guides for the dark theme.  Couldn't find it in the settings panel...

Answer (score 1):

I found it, though not it wasn't apparent at first.  Its in *Edit> Preferences> Themes> 3D Viewport> View Overlay*